# Python: deleting similar objects from a list using difflib.SequenceMatcher

Tags: python

Let's say I have a list of some strings, and there are certain strings there that very, very similar. And I want to delete those *almost duplicates*. For that, I came up with the following code:

```
from difflib import SequenceMatcher

l = ['Apple', 'Appel', 'Aple', 'Mango']
c = [l[0]]

for i in l:
    count = 0
    for j in c:
        if SequenceMatcher(None, i, j).ratio() < 0.7:
            count += 1
    if count == len(c):
        c.append(i)
```

Which seems to work fine but I don't really like nested loops and also this `count` solution looks ugly. But probably it's possible to write it down in a more Pythonic way? Using generators, may be?

Would be grateful for a hint, thanks :)

Comment: I think this would be better on [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think a cleaner way to write this would be to use `difflib` method `get_close_matches`

```
from difflib import get_close_matches

l = ['Apple', 'Appel', 'Aple', 'Mango']
c = []

while l:
    word = l.pop()
    c.append(word)
    l = [x for x in l if x not in get_close_matches(word, l, cutoff=0.7)]
```

Note that this deconstructs `l` so you may want to make a copy of it first.